# codeblock vs VS2010

Tags: winapi, visual-studio-2010

I have got following code:-

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    char ay[256]={0};//HWND hwnd= GetForegroundWindow();
    if( GetClassName(hwnd,ay,256))
    {
        char x[70]={0};
        GetWindowText(hwnd,x,70);
        if(IsWindowVisible(hwnd))
        {
            // CaptureAnImage(hwNd,hwnd);
            HINSTANCE hins= (HINSTANCE) GetWindowLong(hwnd,GWL_HINSTANCE);
            WNDCLASSEX lpwcx;
            GetClassInfoEx(hins,ay,&lpwcx);

            if (MessageBox(0, 
                           strcat(strcat(x, "\r\n"), lpwcx.lpszClassName),
                           "Info", 0x06L) == IDTRYAGAIN)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

void cstm()
{
    EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc,0);
}
```

This runs fine on Codeblocks (with VS 2010 compiler(cl)) but VS2010 gives a corrupted lpwcx value, I have tried the Unicode as well as Ascii to tackle this but no good result at
all. The first lpwcx is correct but later they return class not found(1411) ,although the hinstance and class name is correct.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

```
   strcat(strcat(x, "\r\n"), lpwcx.lpszClassName),
```

The odds that this will overflow the *x* buffer and stomp some local variable values, like *lpwcx", are very high.  70 chars is unreasonably frugal.  If you don't want to use strcat_s() then at least make it bigger.  And yes, initialize lpwcx.cbSize

Answer (score 0):

Always fill in the cbSize member of data blocks before calling any API functions. Many of them rely upon this value to know which version of the data structure they should fill in.

Comment: I cant find cbsize in wndclass its only cbwndextra and cbclsextra  there.